# how to read unique values from excel column using powershell

Tags: powershell

i would like to read unique email id from a column and assign to a local variable, can anyone assist in doing that

my data will be like

[image]

i would like to get unique values from the excel and assign it to a variable using power shell

the variable should hold value in following way Nalin23@bridgestone.com;raj@bridgestone.com;kishan@bridgestone.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the values from an Excel column and return it as array of values, you can use this helper function:

```
function Import-ExcelColumn {
    # returns an array of Excel Column values
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 1)]
        [int]$WorkSheetIndex = 1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [int]$ColumnIndex = 1
    )

    # constants from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection
    $xlDown = -4121
    $xlUp   = -4162

    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $workbook  = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
    $worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($WorkSheetIndex)

    # get the first and last used row indices
    $firstRow = $worksheet.Cells($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).End($xlUp).Row
    $lastRow  = $worksheet.Cells($firstRow, 1).End($xlDown).Row

    # collect the values in this column in variable $result
    # start at $firstRow + 1 to skip the header itself
    $result = for ($row = $firstRow + 1; $row -le $lastRow; $row++) {  
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $ColumnIndex).Value2
    }

    $excel.Quit()
    # IMPORTANT: clean-up used Com objects
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    # $result is an array. PowerShell 'unravels' arrays when returned from a function.
    # to overcome this, prefix the returned array with a unary comma.
    return ,$result
}
```

After that, in your case use it like this:

```
$emailAddresses = ((Import-ExcelColumn -Path 'D:\Test\Map1.xlsx' -ColumnIndex 2) | Select-Object -Unique) -join ';'
```

to get a string:

> Nalin23@bridgestone.com;raj@bridgestone.com;kishan@bridgestone.com

Comment: My excel file gets locked while executing the program can you help

Comment: @KishanM You need to make sure Excel has not opened the same file when you run the code. If need be, check the TaskManager and close al Excel instances. Once a file is open in Excel, it gets locked.

Comment: i have posted another thread as  im not able to past my code here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61892326/how-to-get-unique-values-in-excel-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code you have attempted as a reference for everyone answering the qustion.

With that said, the below code should work for a comma separate value (.csv) file:

```
# Get CSV object
$csv_object    = Import-CSV $path_to_csv

# Find unique entries from email_id column
$unique_emails = $csv_object.email_id | Select -Unique

# Join them with ;
$delim_emails  = $unqiue_emails -join ";"
```