# how to get unique values in excel using powershell

Tags: powershell

i have following code, i this i will read a excel sheet and i will get values but i want a unique values for one column that is MOD_user using that i can send out mail

```
#select excel file you want to read
$file = "C:\Gopi_Kishan\DBBR\Build\Build_Scripts\test.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"

#create new excel COM object
$excel = New-Object -com Excel.Application

#open excel file
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($file)

#select excel sheet to read data
$sheet = $wb.Worksheets.Item($sheetname)

#select total rows
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count

#create new object with Sno, Market, Object Name, Object_Type, Issue_id, Mod_user, Reviewed  properties.
$myData = New-Object -TypeName psobjectl
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Issue_id -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Mod_user -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Reviewed -Value $null
$myData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Request_number -Value $null

$myarray= "gkishan"

#create empty arraylist
#$myArray = @()

for ($i = 2; $i -le $rowMax; $i++)
{
    $objTemp = $myData | Select-Object *

    #read data from each cell
    $objTemp.Sno = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).Text
        $objTemp.Issue_id = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,5).Text
    $objTemp.Mod_user = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,6).Text
    $objTemp.Reviewed = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,7).Text
    $objTemp.Request_number = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,8).Text

    #Echo $objTemp.Market
    #echo $objTemp.name
    #echo $objTemp.Object_Type
    $MARKET_NAME = $objTemp.Market
    $OBJECT_NAME = $objTemp.name
    $OBJECT_TYPE = $objTemp.Object_Type
    $Issue_id = $objTemp.Issue_id
    $Mod_user = $objTemp.Mod_user
    $Reviewed = $objTemp.Reviewed
    $ReqNumber = $objTemp.Request_number
    #Write-Host  $MARKET_NAME ' - ' $OBJECT_NAME ' - ' $OBJECT_TYPE  ' - ' $Issue_id  ' - ' $Mod_user  ' - ' $Reviewed
    #Add-Content $path\$FileLogdate.txt  $MARKET_NAME' - '$OBJECT_NAME' - '$OBJECT_TYPE' - '$Issue_id' - '$Mod_user' - '$Reviewed


}
```

i want to get the unique values from Mod_user

can any one help

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$objTemp.Mod_user = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,6).Text
$unique_mod_users = $objTemp.Mod_user | Select-Object -Unique
```

You can then use `$unique_mod_users` in this way:

```
$Mod_user = $unique_mod_users
```

Or simply use it directly.